# JSValue.toObjectOf returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, javascriptcore

I'm experimenting with JavaScriptCore and `JSValue.toObjectOfClass`. My question is, given the code below why is `ofObjectToClass` returning `nil` instead of an instance of my `Pet` class?

NOTE: This is a pared down example that simulates what I'm trying to do with a much larger codebase. Please excuse its simple nature and feel free to geek out on the inner workings of `ofObjectToClass`. There seems to be precious little info about it.

Here's the code that I'm working with - you can drop it right into a Swift Playground and try it for yourself:

```
import JavaScriptCore

let javascript = """
var Pet = (function() {
    function Pet(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Pet.prototype, 'name', {
        get: function () {return this._name;},
        set: function (name) {this._name = name;}
    });

    return Pet;
})();

var fetchPet = function(name) {
    return new Pet(name);
}
"""

@objc public class Pet: NSObject, JSExport {
    public var name: String?
}

let context = JSContext()!
context.evaluateScript(javascript)
let fcn = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("fetchPet")!
let petValue = fcn.call(withArguments: ["Fido"])
print("petValue.name is \(petValue?.forProperty("name")?.toString() ?? "???")")
if let petObj = petValue?.toObjectOf(Pet.self) as? Pet {
    print("pet.name is \(petObj.name)")
}
else {
    print("pet is nil :(")
}
```

And here's the output that I get:

```
petValue.name is Fido
pet is nil :(
```

And the output that I'm expecting:

```
petValue.name is Fido
pet.name is Fido
```

Thanks for looking and have a good weekend!

Edit: I'm aware of the Apple documentation that states, "...nil if the value cannot be converted to the expected class." I'm after the *why*.

Answer (score 0):

***why is `ofObjectToClass` returning `nil` instead of an instance of my `Pet` class?***

Because your JavaScript class `Pet` has nothing to do with your Swift class `Pet`.

You need to export your Swift class `Pet` explicitly:

```
import JavaScriptCore

let javascript = """
var fetchPet = function(name) {
    return new Pet(name);
};
"""

@objc protocol PetProtocol: JSExport {
    var name: String {get set}

    init(name: String)
}

class Pet: NSObject, PetProtocol {
    var name: String

    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let context = JSContext()!
context.setObject(Pet.self, forKeyedSubscript: "Pet" as NSString) //<-
context.evaluateScript(javascript)
let fcn = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("fetchPet")!
let petValue = fcn.call(withArguments: ["Fido"])
print("petValue.name is \(petValue?.forProperty("name")?.toString() ?? "???")")
if let petObj = petValue?.toObjectOf(Pet.self) as? Pet {
    print("pet.name is \(petObj.name)")
}
else {
    print("pet is nil :(")
}
```

Comment: Your response suggests that I can't declare a `Pet` object in JS and a `Pet` class in Swift. Is my understanding correct? Assume for a moment that I can't change the JavaScript code to remove the `Pet` object  - what other approaches can I use to solve this issue?

Comment: With the assumption, nothing. Just use it as a `JSValue`.

Comment: This example won't work as it is (at least in an Xcode 10 playground): I'm getting a SIGABRT on setObjectForKeyedSubscript. If I comment out the `init` declaration in `PetProtocol`, the output is `petValue.name is undefined pet is nil :(`... Thoughts?

Comment: @sherb, My code is confirmed to work in the Command Line Tool project of Xcode 10.2.1, I have created an iOS project including it and works fine. I do not know why it does not work in the Playground, you should better send a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Doubly confirming that this example appears to be broken in Swift Playgrounds as of Version 12.3 (12C33), but does work when used in a command line tool or app context.